# Comparing multiple pandas columns of different length to access a final column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare two columns from two different dfs, to return a final column from the second df where both columns match (comparing 'A' with 'D' and 'B' with 'E' to return value in 'F' to new column). Is there a convenient way to do this?

df1

```
   A  B  
0  1  string1  
1  4  string2  
2  7  string3  
3  8  string4
```

df2

```
   D  E  F
0  0  string3  5
1  4  string2  6
2  3  string1  10
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is new col containing values of F where both col's match

Comment: For the above example you want to return as 6?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below:

```
df1.merge(df2,left_on=['A','B'],right_on=['D','E'])['F']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,7], 'B':['String1','String2','String3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'D':[0,4,3], 'E':['String3','String2','String1'], 'F':[5,6,10]})

mask = (df1.A == df2.D) & (df1.B == df2.E)

print(df2[mask]['F'])
```

Output:

```
1    6                                                                                                                                
Name: F, dtype: int64
```